# Understanding lenses for virtual reality and viewing a screen very close to eyes

Tags: optics, lenses

I'm trying to understand the physics of the technology involved in making a simple virtual reality headset.

More specifically, I just care how does one make it so they can see and focus on a screen right in front of their face?

I ask my question in picture format below:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help with my understanding here.

Answer (score 2):

Two things need to be done.

- a sharp image needs to be formed on the retina,
- as perceived by the eye/brain the image needs to be upright.

Because the smartphone is so close to the eye, the rays entering the eye are highly divergent and they need to be made less divergent after passing through the lens.
This is achieved by using a convex lens of short focal length with the smartphone placed at or within the focal plane of the lens.
The image produced by the lens is upright.
This is a magnifying glass arrangement.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm trying to understand it. First: is the 'object' the smartphone? Second, how to calculate the proper focal length, and the lens which achieves this? Can one buy adjustable convex lenses of sufficient size (similar size to the phone) so I could just adjust and test? Cheers!

Comment: Object is the smartphone.  To get the final image at infinity you need the smartphone in the focal plane of the lens. Focal length of order 5 cm and aspherical ie corrected for possible lens aberrations. I suggest that you search the Internet where you will find a multitude of designs eg [DIY 3D Virtual Reality Goggles](http://www.hutter1.net/puzzles/3dvrglass.htm) and there are some which are basic diy in that the lenses are made from a soda bottle.